# Using auto in output parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Is there a way to use auto keyword in this scenario:

```
void foo(bar& output){
    output = bar();
} 

int main(){
   //Imaginary code
   auto a;
   foo(a);
}
```

Of course, it impossible to know what type of `a`. So, the solution should be to merge them in one sentence in a way or another. Is this available?

Comment: I don't think so.. What would happen if you added an overload to `foo`?

Comment: If you don't know the type of `a` when writing the program, you have an impossible problem. For the function the solution is templates, but you do need to know the type of the variable you declare, one way or another.

Comment: Simple answer is no (BTW What do you mean by merge them into one sentence).

Comment: auto keyword tells the compiler to  deduce the data type of RHS by using the intializer , so without a initializer the compiler cannot deduce the type

Comment: Stated simpler: auto cannot be used unless the type can be derived in the same statement in which it appears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to default-initialize an object of the type a given function expects as an argument.

You can't do this with `auto`, but you could write a trait to extract the type a function expects, then use that to declare your variable:

```
namespace detail {
    //expects the argument number and a function type
    template <std::size_t N, typename Func>
    struct arg_n;

    //does all the work
    template <std::size_t N, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct arg_n <N, Ret (Args...)> {
        using type = std::remove_reference_t<
                         std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Args...>>
                     >;   
    };
}

//helper to make usage neater
template <std::size_t N, typename Func>
using arg_n = typename detail::arg_n<N, Func>::type;
```

Then you use it like so:

```
//type of the first argument expected by foo
arg_n<0,decltype(foo)> a{};
foo(a);
```

Of course, as soon as you overload the function this all fails horribly.

Comment: This is awesome although I did not understand all the pattern but the result is exactly what I want. However, I am afraid using it in real-world program because someone (few years later) will wish that the one who writes this code to go to hell :D

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Actually, this kind of code is pretty normal in a generic context. You might want some more comments if you think maintainers will find it obtuse.

Answer (score 4):

```
bar foo()
{
    return bar{};
}

int main()
{
    auto a = foo();
}
```

All the modern compilers will do copy-elision, there will be no copies at all.

Comment: While this exhibits use of auto, it avoids the question because it isn't using an out parameter.

Comment: @ChrisBetti In this situation better to not pass reference to some constructed instance, then assign to it the new instance. Better return by value and assign it to newly created `auto` variable.

Comment: I 100% agree with you.